# Unrecognized selector on calling Google Toolbox for Mac NSString category method in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, categories, google-toolbox-for-mac

I'm building a static library for use in an iOS project, and I want to decode XML entities returned from a web service. I've grabbed [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) and added the following files to my project:

- GTMDefines.h
- GTMNSString+HTML.h
- GTMNSString+HTML.m

Then in my own .m file I'm doing this:

```
#import "GTMNSString+HTML.h"

// then in one of my methods:
NSString *value = [anotherNSStringValue gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];
```

The code compiles fine, but when I run the app that uses my static library it crashes with a `NSInvalidArgumentException`, complaining that the `gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML` selector isn't recognised for `NSString`:

```
2011-02-10 12:21:38.401 MyApp[20356:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71403e0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0111bbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x012705c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0111d6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0108d366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0108cf22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   MyApp                               0x00028dcf -[GSMyAppXMLParser parseData:] + 714
    // Rest of stack trace removed
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

I've found a few similar issues on Stack Overflow, and in each case the questioner has subsequently commented that they fixed it by tweaking a linker setting - but without disclosing which setting! If anyone can help me with this I'd be forever grateful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m guessing that would be the `-ObjC` and `-all_load` flags.

You add these to the ‘Other Linker Flags’ of **the app** that links agains the library, **not** the library itself.

For more info see: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1490.html

Comment: seriously..i still don't get this zillions of build configurations and flags!!